How to reload a pwa app in Chrome browser via chrome.exe
with the command i can start a pwa app in Google Chrome browser successfull:
chrome.exe --profile-directory=Default --app-id=fhcjoclgiemeeiaipbbckbpamih
But i dont know how to simply refresh the pwa app. Its the same when i press STRG + R Key.
Does anyone know how to refresh/reload a pwa App by chrome.exe/chrome_proxy.exe?
regards
Im search in https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
